# What controls a laptop's fan speed? Vostro 3560 overheating

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, overheating

I own a vostro 3560 and I know about the terrible ventilation and heat dissipation problems it has. I've tried several configurations of the copper sheet fix, but what I've found is that my system's fan is very active for the initial 5 to 10 minutes and then, and specially if I watch video (youtube in brower or PotPlayer, the fan seems to idle at 2600 RPM and does not ramp up to cool the system down.

I've noticed that after I installed HWiNFO64, I find myself pressing the Fan button and then the System Auto button, but if HWInfo is NOT open or is not on top of other windows, the fan will only idle.

[image]

[image]

What exactly controls or tells the fan at what speed should it spin?

Could I have messed up those values installing HWiNFO64? I've reinstalled the BIOS, the video drivers but the solution is always the same: fan is quite active at startup, only to stay at idling speeds while watching video and eventually, laptop shuts down due to intense overheating.

Hope someone can point me to a productive and useful suggestion as to what I can do to regain proper fan speeds.

These values are almost at idle, just typing on a browser and BitTorrent running in the background:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually the BIOS controls the fan speed

If you can take a look at your fan on your laptop here is a thing to remember

2-wires
Thermally controlled

3 or 4-wires
PWM Controlled (Pulse Width Modulation) (BIOS)

3 wire
Wire color Black and Red (Power)

Other color (usually yellow) (RPM Read)

4 wire
Wire color black (common ground)

All other colors represent of the 3 wires of each pole (confirmation on answer required) (haven't had one of these fans yet to determine correctly)

Also if you have one of those laptops that have pices that come off like a ram door, hdd door with out anything falling off and or out and disrupt what you are doing then raise the back end of the laptop by using a cooler pad you can get somewhere as I had an HP Laptop that got extremely warm to too hot to use doing this I would recommend only as a last resort as you can actually disconnect the hard drive and or bump the ram and it will just shut off to just add air flow if you still want to use that laptop